# Adding ?ref=nf to all links on existing page

Tags: facebook, category-blog

Currently, on the blog page: http://www.sagu.edu/news/page-14?ref=nf

The page number links contain the text "?ref=nf" appended to it.  I have no idea how its being generated.

However, when viewing the cannoical link /news/page-14, the "?ref="nf" is removed on the page links.[image]

Comment: per my answer I can't see that on the link provided — can you expand further on your question with relevant details. Like when does this happen, what browser are you using etc…

Comment: Also verify that you don't have some random browser plugin that is adding this to each link, similar to how skype's plugin buggers all the phone numbers on a page and breaks formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... no they don't, have you eliminated your browser as the possibility?

That is to say, if you normally use Google Chrome try Safari, Firefox or something from Microsoft…

[image: Screenshot of site]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I edited the original post to provide more details.